# Can I rotate place(s) names with the "transform rotate" css on my google map (api)?

Tags: android, css, google-maps-api-3, rotation

I am rotating my google map on my mobile internet page with the following with inline css;

```
<div id="map" style="transform:rotate(45deg); -ms- 
transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */ -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); 
/* Firefox */ -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome 
 */ -o-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera */"></div>
```

That works fine. But I am also using "places" to show googles customer locations like restaurants etc. The names show up fine, but they also rotate 45 degrees. That would mean that when I rotate to 180 degrees, the names would be upside down.

I can't find code to keep the names horizontal at 0 degrees (or 360) to keep them readable.
I tried rotation with tilt and 90/180/270 degrees, but it doesn't always work and
the map has to be in satelite mode for that.

On the official google map app on mobile phones, rotate works with two fingers and the
place names stay horizontal. I wish I could do that programmatically.

But for now I would be happy to just keep the places-names horizontal.

Any idea's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I am now using a different google map type namely "vector" i.o. the default "raster" together with a map-id.
It's slightly slower, but I can turn the map with two fingers on a phone and change the heading degrees to any value (0-360).